# fstab filesystem type for NTFS -- 'ntfs' or 'ntfs-3g'?

Tags: linux, fstab, ntfs

I have a question about the difference between 'ntfs' and 'ntfs-3g' in the filesystem type field in the /etc/fstab file. My Linux distribution is Xubuntu; I suppose the answer may well vary between distros.

My question is basically which is best to use in which contexts. It seems that most websites tell you to use 'ntfs-3g', which is a FUSE driver for NTFS under linux. From some searching around it seems to be the case that 'ntfs' (without the -3g part) typically refers to a kernel driver, rather than the ntfs-3g userland driver. The only problem with that is that I've been using 'ntfs' in my fstabs rather than 'ntfs-3g', while a check of /proc/filesystems doesn't show any listing for ntfs.

Can anyone shed some light on what the precise difference in semantics (if there is any) is between 'ntfs' and 'ntfs-3g'? Is it safe to assume that if mount sees 'ntfs' it will search for a driver which supports that type of filesystem and find the ntfs-3g driver if it's installed?

---

EDIT: I forgot to add that 'ntfs' has worked whenever I've used it -- I was simply curious as to the answer, and I wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something iffy.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

They're identical - both use ntfs-3g in (current) Ubuntu; the `ntfs` utils are just symlinked to `ntfs-3g`.

```
# which mount.ntfs
/sbin/mount.ntfs
# which mount.ntfs-3g
/sbin/mount.ntfs-3g
# ls /sbin/mount.ntfs* -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 2011-03-01 21:13 /sbin/mount.ntfs -> mount.ntfs-3g
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 2011-03-01 21:13 /sbin/mount.ntfs-3g -> /bin/ntfs-3g
```

Comment: File system utils are trixy things. fsck/e2fsck will take you down a rabbit hole of symlinks too. Especially on a RedHat based distro.

Answer (score 16):

The traditional NTFS kernel driver is read only. If you use `ntfs` in your fstab it will attempt to use that kernel driver, and mount your NTFS as read only

The `ntfs-3g` is the newer FUSE driver (as you mention) and will mount the partitions as read-write is you use it in NTFS.

Some distros have started treating them as one and the same, but as of about a year ago, using `ntfs` in fstab in Ubuntu would result in the file system not being writeable. I guess it might depend upon the version of Xubuntu you have installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I accepted Shane Madden's answer because he was just a bit faster, but your answer was also very helpful.